# Sending label field in mailer Ploneformgen

Tags: plone, ploneformgen

I am trying to get the mailer to include a rich label field from my Ploneformgen form.  I have gone into the template of the mailer adapter and added this code:

```
<tal:block tal:content="python:request.form.get('sss-label', None)"/>
```

'sss-label is the name of the rich label field.  This code works for displaying other items on the form, just not this one.  Any ideas?

John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only form inputs are stored in request/form, so you'll need to look this up from the field object:

```
<tal:block tal:content="structure context/sss-label/fgField/default" />
```

"fgField" is PFG's storage for an actual field inside a field context object. Rich-text fields have their label html stored in the field's default.